# what are the API endpoints ModelViewSet

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I already managed to perform get one and get all requests , i'm now trying to delete and create new users through url .

views.py :

```
class EtudiantViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
 queryset=Etudiant.objects.all()
 serializer_class=EtudiantSerializer
```

router.py :

```
router=routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('etudiants',EtudiantViewSet)
```

urls.py :

```
urlpatterns = [

 url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
 path('api/',include(router.urls)),]
```

models.py :

```
class Etudiant(models.Model):

 id=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
 nom=models.CharField(max_length=20)
 prenom=models.CharField(max_length=20)

 cne=models.CharField(max_length=10)
 email=models.EmailField()
 tel=models.CharField(max_length=10)

 def __str__(self):
     return 'Nom : {} , Prénom : {}'.format(self.nom,self.prenom)
```

serializers.py :

```
class EtudiantSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
 class Meta :
     model=Etudiant
     fields='__all__'
```

Any recommendations ?

Comment: Did you try sending an HTTP DELETE request to /api/edutiants/id/ ?

Comment: yes it returns me the deleted object but when I go to 127.0.0.1:8000/api/etudiants/ The deleted object is still there

Comment: In my terminal it displays "DELETE /api/etudiants/ HTTP/1.1" 405 43
 in RED

Comment: 405 response code means "Method not allowed". Did you share all of the code for  EtudiantViewSet? If not, can you share the rest?

Comment: yes i shared all the code

Comment: should i add another method ?

Comment: From the logs it seems like you are sending the request to "127.0.0.1:8000/api/etudiants/", whereas it should be "127.0.0.1:8000/api/etudiants/id/", note the id at the end, it should be the id of the instnace you want to delete

Comment: ok i think i just pasted the wrong error message , apologize for that . 
Here is why i tried just now : I sent a delete request to 127.0.0.1:8000/api/etudiants/1 in POSTMAN , which gave me the following message : "DELETE /api/etudiants/1 HTTP/1.1" 301 0 ( so it worked i guess) 
But when i go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/etudiants/  the object that i just deleted is still there why ?

Comment: Can you append a slash (/) character to  your request url?  I think the request is being redirected with a GET request without it (i.e "/api/etudiants/1/" instead of "/api/etudiants/1")

Comment: and you should look at the exact response in postman, what is the 301 redirect for? (what's the `Location` header of the response?)

Comment: It worked ! , thank you , what about updating and creating please ?

Comment: How can i send PUT or POST request ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have used `ModelViewSet` for controlling api.

Which provides you following urls as per your declaration.

- `<host>/api/etudiants/` *POST*
- `<host>/api/etudiants/<Etudiant id>/` *DELETE*
- `<host>/api/etudiants/<Etudiant id>/` *PUT*
- `<host>/api/etudiants/<Etudiant id>/` *PATCH*
- `<host>/api/etudiants/<Etudiant id>/` *GET*
- `<host>/api/etudiants/` *GET* (List endpoint)

**Deletion**: You may use `<host>/api/etudiants/<Etudiant id>` replace `<Etudiant id>` with your `Etudiant` object's id and call `DELETE` http method on that endpoint.

**Creation**: Use `<host>/api/etudiants/` add *json payload* then call `POST` http method on that endpoint.

If this would not help you than put your comment below.

Comment: using postman i sent a post request to this url : 127.0.0.1:8000/api/etudiants/ but it displays : "detail": "Unsupported media type \"text/plain\" in request.